# AngularJS Animate height of ul

Tags: css, angularjs

I am implementing a bootstrap theme that has a log of jQuery innards that I don't want to use, since we are using angular. I have very little flexibility on the markup in regards to adding new tags (can't surround my ul w/ a div) because the CSS, which I'd rather not change refers to .sub-menu via "x > .sub-menu > y" (which sucks for me)

I want to animate the hide/show of .sub-menu shown here:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="menu in menuItems" ng-class="{open: menu.isOpen}">
        <a ng-click="menu.isOpen=!menu.isOpen" ng-bind="menu.title"></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu" ng-show="menu.isOpen">
            <li ng-repeat="subMenu in menu.subMenuItems">
                <a ng-href="{{subMenu.url}}" ng-bind="subMenu.title"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UTQ8B/) to help illustrate that it works w/ opacity, but not height

Comment: You can't use ng-animate? [here is a plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/4yEBCpKeSqj9yr4Ul6Hz)

Comment: ng-animate went away w/ angular 1.2

Comment: Hmmmm... does that include [this module](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate)

Comment: @J.Wells Yes, that module is available in 1.2, but to clarify I'd prefer to handle this via the CSS animation mechanism rather than via JavaScript

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `ngAnimate` *module* (not the directive) along with the `ng-show` directive you already have.

What you'd need to do is:

1. Add a reference to the `angular-animate.js` file.
2. Add a reference to `ngAnimate` to your module definition:

   ```
   angular.module('yourModule', ['ngAnimate']);
   ```
3. Then add a custom class (or use the existing `sub-menu` class) to your
   `ul` you're showing with `ng-show`, then you have to set up some CSS
   animations:

```css
.sub-menu {
  -webkit-transform: all linear 500ms;
  transform: all linear 500ms;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}

/* required or animations will fail */
.sub-menu.ng-hide-add,
.sub-menu.ng-hide-remove {
  display: block !important;
}

.sub-menu.ng-hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Here's a contrived example: http://plnkr.co/edit/4eRInJzMqccDpxChYHaT?p=preview